# Fusion Table Filters not able to update map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

Below is my code attached. The map is loaded once but isn't after once it is updated the query of the layer

Please if someone could provide me with an solution soon
the default map is loaded always once the option is also selected and that is the main issue.
Map according to the filters is not produced.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport"></meta>
<title>Rise Project (Responses) - Google Fusion Tables</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body, #googft-mapCanvas {
  height: 800px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 600px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//var tableId = '1hVh2fZH52W9qCM4rMnqzjG6z3lPM5B970H__hLUn';

  function initialize() {
    var tableId = '1hVh2fZH52W9qCM4rMnqzjG6z3lPM5B970H__hLUn';
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) ||
      (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
    if (isMobile) {
      var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
      viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
    }
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
    mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '100%' : '600px';
    mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '100%' : '600px';
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.3765560012846, 77.97422298410743),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend-open'));
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map: map,
      heatmap: { enabled: false },
       query: {
              select: "*",
              from: tableId
            },
      options: {
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 3
      }
    });
   window.alert(layer.query.where);

    if (isMobile) {
      var legend = document.getElementById('googft-legend');
      var legendOpenButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-open');
      var legendCloseButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-close');
      legend.style.display = 'none';
      legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
      legendCloseButton.style.display = 'block';
      legendOpenButton.onclick = function() {
        legend.style.display = 'block';
        legendOpenButton.style.display = 'none';
      }
      legendCloseButton.onclick = function() {
        legend.style.display = 'none';
        legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
        window.alert("BEfore");

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delivery'),
            'change', function() {
              updateMap(layer, tableId);

        });


} 

      function updateMap(layer, tableId) {
        var delivery = document.getElementById('delivery').value;

        window.alert(delivery + "In Update Map");
        if (delivery) {

          layer.setOptions({
            query: {
              select: "*",
              from: tableId, 
              where: "Boys/Girls = '" + delivery + "'"
            }
          });
        } else {
          layer.setOptions({
            query: {
              select: "*",
              from: tableId
            }
          });
        }
      }
window.alert("Out of function");
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
window.alert("End");
</script>
</head>

<body>
<br><br><br><p align="center">
  <div id="googft-mapCanvas">

  </div>
  <label>Boys/Girls?</label>
    <select id="delivery">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option value="Boys">Boys</option>
      <option value="Girls">Girls</option>
    </select></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is invalid (you need a ' before and after the column name):

```
where: "Boys/Girls = '" + delivery + "'"
```

should be:

```
where: "'Boys/Girls' = '" + delivery + "'"
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bcsnzj63/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var tableId = '1hVh2fZH52W9qCM4rMnqzjG6z3lPM5B970H__hLUn';
  var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) ||
    (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
  if (isMobile) {
    var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
    viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
  }
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.3765560012846, 77.97422298410743),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend-open'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    heatmap: {
      enabled: false
    },
    query: {
      select: "*",
      from: tableId
    },
    options: {
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 3
    }
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(layer.get("query")));

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delivery'), 'change',
    function() {
      updateMap(layer, tableId);
    });
}

function updateMap(layer, tableId) {
  var delivery = document.getElementById('delivery').value;
  console.log(delivery + " In Update Map");
  if (delivery) {
    layer.setOptions({
      query: {
        select: "*",
        from: tableId,
        where: "'Boys/Girls' = '" + delivery + "'"
      }
    });
    console.log("tableId=" + tableId + ", delivery=" + delivery);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(layer.get("query")));
  } else {
    layer.setOptions({
      query: {
        select: "*",
        from: tableId
      }
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googft-mapCanvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<label>Boys/Girls?</label>
<select id="delivery">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Boys">Boys</option>
  <option value="Girls">Girls</option>
</select>
<div id="googft-mapCanvas">

</div>
```